# Converting an IP to a Long in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use the `ip2country` table to show the country flags of the users on my website.

The simplest thing I came up with is to write an SQL statement that takes the users from the session table and queries to see if their respective IP is in a certain range to figure out their country/flag.

It's simple but also dangerous, because when there are 300 users online to show and I fetch them from the session table, querying their countries to display the flags, there will surely be a big memory usage.

Now I tried this to do it in one single query:

```sql
SELECT 
  s.session_ip, 
  ipc.*
FROM 
  session AS s
    LEFT JOIN ip2country AS ipc 
    ON ipc.ip_lo <= s.session_ip AND ipc.ip_hi >= s.session_ip
WHERE 
  s.session_time  > '".( time() - 60) )."'
```

Now it's clear that the above query is wrong because the IPs saved in the `ip2country` table is an integer, e.g. 1000013824, and the IPs stored in the session table are the string representations of the IPs, e.g. 193.169.0.0

I know how to convert from an IP to a long in PHP with the `ip2long()`, but is there any equivalent method in MySQL so I don't have to do two queries?

Comment: still i have overload and problematic , any example on showing flag of online users !?

Comment: Probably out of the scope of this question?

Answer (score 48):

SELECT INET_NTOA(1000013824) -> 59.155.0.0

SELECT INET_ATON('193.169.0.0') -> 3249078272

Enjoy :)

Comment: and my query would be :  ON INET_ATON(ipc.ip_lo) <=s.session_ip AND INET_ATON(ipc.ip_hi) >=s.session_ip  ????

Comment: How about trying it out to see what happens?

Comment: An easier way to distinguish each is that NTOA can be read as "Number TO Address", and ATON as "Address TO Number"